# postgres psql - how to change separator to comma

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using Postgres psql in a windows batch file

```
psql -h %hostip% -p %port% -d %%a -U %username% -t -c "select table_catalog,table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables" -o out.txt
```

It saves the data in out.txt with default separator '|' .

```
 mydb      | public       | table1
 mydb      | public       | table2
 mydb      | public       | table3
```

But I want to get output like,

```
 mydb,public,table1
 mydb,public,table2
 mydb,public,table3
```

How to achieve this.  Have tried -F, --field-separator but nothing worked. Is there any different way to modify default separator

Answer (score 1):

Add the `psql` option `--csv` to get the result in CSV format.